# Primeng data-table row does't show cell values

Tags: angular, primeng-datatable

I used Primeng data-table for display selected values from angular select.

Whenever select the option in dropdown that selected values need to be display in primeng data-table.

Here problem I got empty row instead selected value:

[image]

The Code:

```
 <mat-form-field fxFlex="50%">
   <mat-label>Select The NAICS Name Or NAICS Code.</mat-label>
   <mat-select multiple name="cnae"(selectionChange)="cnaeChangeValue($event)">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let cnae of listOfcnae.default.cnaeData" 
       [value]="cnae">
    {{cnae.TextField }}
     </mat-option>
   </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
<p-table [columns]="cnaeCols" [value]="selectedCnaeValues" [paginator]="true"[rows]="10">
  <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
     <tr>
         <th *ngFor="let col of columns">
          {{col.header}}
         </th>
     </tr>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-columns="columns">
    <tr>
        <td *ngFor="let col of columns">
        {{rowData[col.filed]}}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </ng-template>
</p-table> 

ts code:
ngOnInit() {
this.cnaeCols = [
      { field:"RowNumber", header: "RowNumber"},
      { filed:"TextField", header: "TextField"},
      { field:"ValueField", header: "ValueField"},
    ]
}
 cnaeChangeValue(eventVal) {
    this.selectedCnaeValues.push(eventVal.value);
  }

And json value:
[
{
 "RowNumber": "1",
 "TextField": "1011201 - FRIGORÍFICO - ABATE DE BOVINOS",
  "ValueField": "168"
}
]
```

Comment: will you please create stackblitz for this to provide solution much faster

Comment: sorry my machine having problem stackblitz result section. The result is not diaplay in my machine i have tried so many times

Comment: {{rowData[col.filed]}}
 { filed:"TextField", header: "TextField"}, - there should be 'field' not 'filed'

Comment: @porgo, Ooops but not solved still got empty row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the material dropdown `(selectionChange)="cnaeChangeValue($event)` on selection return all selected items in the array and that you are trying to push in the array that's why the table is not showing data.

```
cnaeChangeValue(eventVal) {
    this.selectedCnaeValues = eventVal.value; // Will work
  }
```

[**Solution Created on stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mzd42p?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Hope this will help!

Comment: If i assign json values is directly it's correct. I need to display based on angular multiple select options. I  seclect 4option in angular multiple select means that four values should be display in primng datatable. I need to display specific value from the bulk JSON values.

Comment: I got your problem after push value in array use spread operator to refresh data - this.selectedCnaeValues = [...this.selectedCnaeValues];

Comment: I have added Json values but only one value is display in table

Comment: why are not dirctly assigned like this this.selectedCnaeValues = eventVal.value;

Comment: I have array values i need to display those selected values form json values and push empty this.selectedCnaeValues  array

Comment: because eventVal.value is return array which you are trying to push in array that's why it's not working

Comment: If this solve your problem so please be kind and accept the answer so that others will get help from it